# Enable scheduling on Spring Boot without EnableScheduling annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have a Spring Boot service deployed as fat jar in production without EnableScheduling and it will take some time until we can deploy a fix.

Is any possibility to enable scheduling from command line without redeploying the Spring Boot jar?

I couldn't find any property on documentation to enable it.

I tried defining the task scheduler in xml configuration file and importing at startup, but couldn't make this work.

Comment: Can you even import an XML configuration file without changing the code? I always thought you needed to somehow declare an `@ImportResource` somewhere to make it work.